# How do i get Facebook id

Tags: javascript, .net, facebook, api

iam building a rss based web-plugin to collect feeds from social media. At the moment the user have to enter the facebook Id manually that they want to get the feed from.

I Found this site http://findmyfacebookid.com/ which does exactly what i want. 
If i can integrate something similar in my configuration part of the plugin it would be so much smoother user experience.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an ajax call to get a user's facebook id :

```js
var name = 'zuck';
$.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/' + name, {
  format: "json"
}).done(function(data) {
  $('#output').html(data.id); // FB Id of his founder
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Id of Mark Zuckerberg :
<div id="output"></div>
```